# How to install keymagic or unicode?

Tags: keyboard, unicode

How to install "keymagic" or "unicode"?

I am on ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: Looking at [the source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntumm/files/ibus-keymagic/), it looks like there have not been any packages prepared for 21.10. You may need to downgrade to 20.04 then [follow the installation instructions from KeyMagic](https://keymagic.net/installation/linux/) to have this work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use packages from 20.04 LTS [official Ubuntu-MM LoCo Team PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekokoye2007/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=focal) on your 21.10 system using commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:kokoye2007/ppa
sudo sed -i "s/impish/focal/g" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kokoye2007-ubuntu-ppa-impish.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ibus-keymagic
```